# How to get CPU usage and RAM usage without exec?

Tags: php, cpu-usage, ram, bandwidth, system-information

How does VBulletin get the system information without the use of `exec`? Is there any other information I can get about the server without exec? I am interested in:

- bandwidth used
- system type
- CPU speed/usage/count
- RAM usage

Comment: I have some experince to get cpu load on windows and i post it at :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538251/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-and-memory-useage/13666951#13666951](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538251/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-and-memory-useage/13666951#13666951) Hope it help .

Answer (score 51, accepted):

**Use [PHPSysInfo](http://phpsysinfo.sourceforge.net/)** library

phpSysInfo is a open source PHP script that displays information about the host being accessed. It will displays things like:

- Uptime
- CPU
- Memory
- SCSI, IDE, PCI
- Ethernet
- Floppy
- Video Information

It directly parsed parses `/proc` and does not use `exec`.

---

**Another way is to use [Linfo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/linfo/)**. It is a very fast **cross-platform** php script that describes the host server in extreme detail, giving information such as ram usage, disk space, raid arrays, hardware, network cards, kernel, os, samba/cups/truecrypt status, temps, disks, and much more.

Comment: @Ronan - it reads directly from /proc, provided open_basedir() is not in effect. So, you should fall back to exec() if that restriction is in place.

Comment: i mean will it work on a shared hosting or does it need some functions enabled (like exec) , my script will be installed by many customers on many hosting plans/dedicated servers and stuff , i need something to work on everything , or with functions that could be enabled ...

Comment: @Ronan: Yes, it does not use `exec`. Try installing that script on your web-server to quickly check. It works on my shared server.

Comment: What if PHPSysInfo tells me that file_exists(/proc/net/dev) does not exist on my machine?

Comment: As a note to an old post by someone from the future; these are both licenced under GPL, not MIT or Apache. So you must disclose the source of your project; I'd be careful if you're planning to use this for business applications where you're not allowed to disclose your source.

Comment: Using this library is super useful. I noticed one can also get the info in XML or JSON format when adding this to your string in the URL for example:  **/phpsysinfo/xml.php?plugin=complete&json** like it shows on their homepage.

Answer (score 11):

This is what I use on Linux servers. It still uses `exec`, but other questions point here as duplicate, and there is no [good] suggestion for those. It *should* work on every distro, but if it doesn't, try messing with `$get_cores + 1` offset.

CPU in percent of cores used (5 min avg):

```
$exec_loads = sys_getloadavg();
$exec_cores = trim(shell_exec("grep -P '^processor' /proc/cpuinfo|wc -l"));
$cpu = round($exec_loads[1]/($exec_cores + 1)*100, 0) . '%';
```

RAM in percent of total used (realtime):

```
$exec_free = explode("\n", trim(shell_exec('free')));
$get_mem = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $exec_free[1]);
$mem = round($get_mem[2]/$get_mem[1]*100, 0) . '%';
```

RAM in GB used (realtime):

```
$exec_free = explode("\n", trim(shell_exec('free')));
$get_mem = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $exec_free[1]);
$mem = number_format(round($get_mem[2]/1024/1024, 2), 2) . '/' . number_format(round($get_mem[1]/1024/1024, 2), 2);
```

Here is what's in the `$get_mem` array if you need to calc other facets:

```
[0]=>row_title [1]=>mem_total [2]=>mem_used [3]=>mem_free [4]=>mem_shared [5]=>mem_buffers [6]=>mem_cached
```

Bonus, here is how to get the uptime:

```
$exec_uptime = preg_split("/[\s]+/", trim(shell_exec('uptime')));
$uptime = $exec_uptime[2] . ' Days';
```

Comment: sad part that it uses exec :)

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
function get_server_load() 
{
    $load=array();
    if (stristr(PHP_OS, 'win')) 
    {
        $wmi = new COM("Winmgmts://");
        $server = $wmi->execquery("SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor");  
        $cpu_num = 0;
        $load_total = 0;
        foreach($server as $cpu)
        {
            $cpu_num++;
            $load_total += $cpu->loadpercentage;
        }

        $load[]= round($load_total/$cpu_num);

    } 
    else
    {
        $load = sys_getloadavg();
    }
    return $load;
}
echo implode(' ',get_server_load());
```

Comment: COM extension for Windows isn't enabled by default in PHP, and certainly not in production mode.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use for instant CPU usage without 1 second delay

```
$cpu = shell_exec('top -bn1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | sed "s/.*, *\([0-9.]*\)%* id.*/\1/" | awk \'{print 100 - $1}\'');
```

Comment: Upvoted the effort but this either does not work or only works on one core or something, keeps outputting 1000 when my usage is 9%

Answer (score 0):

after searching on forums and trying many methods, best accurate is this:

```
$stat1 = file('/proc/stat'); 
sleep(1); 
$stat2 = file('/proc/stat'); 
$info1 = explode(" ", preg_replace("!cpu +!", "", $stat1[0])); 
$info2 = explode(" ", preg_replace("!cpu +!", "", $stat2[0])); 
$dif = array(); 
$dif['user'] = $info2[0] - $info1[0]; 
$dif['nice'] = $info2[1] - $info1[1]; 
$dif['sys'] = $info2[2] - $info1[2]; 
$dif['idle'] = $info2[3] - $info1[3]; 
$total = array_sum($dif); 
$cpu = array(); 
foreach($dif as $x=>$y) $cpu[$x] = round($y / $total * 100, 1);
print_r($cpu);
```

Comment: This does not show the total cpu usage on the server, like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38085813/1920003