# Getting system resource usage in PHP

Tags: php, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to make an app for my phone that will allow me to manage my server remotely. I would like to be able to have this app display stats about the server such as resource usage + system uptime, however I am having difficulty.

My server is running windows server 2008 R2, and all the answers I have found are for UNIX systems. I have tried that many different solutions that I would be here forever if I were to list them.

My server is running on SoYouStart, so I did think about using their Real-Time-Monitoring API, however I find using their API extremely difficult and I run into issues constantly with it.

I need to get System Uptime and Ram usage percentage into a file (preferably JSON) which my mobile app can then access.

If there is a solution baseon on the OVH/SYS API, I'm happy to use that or a PHP script to update a JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

1) See this URL:

[How do you get server CPU usage and RAM usage with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949295/how-to-get-server-cpu-usage-and-ram-usage-with-php)

2) Once you have the system usage, you can save this information in JSON or any other format in a file onto a URL (this file is updated every x seconds ...).

3) Access this JSON file over URL for your mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need basic memory / CPU / disk usage information you don't need to complicate things with advanced APIs. You can use the `com_dotnet` extension on Windows or the `sys_getloadavg()` function on Linux.
The `memory_get_usage()` function will show the amount of used memory. See more details [here](http://coding.bmain.net/tutorials/php/get_system_information_resources_consumption)