# MySQL query sometimes fast, often slow

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I'm having trouble with a MySQL query sometimes taking a few seconds and sometimes taking 30.  I'm trying to figure out if it's the query or if the problem is being on a shared server.

Some background: table has about 2 million rows and every field with user data is encrypted (customer requirement).  Since fields are encrypted, I can't do any indexes.  Here's a query that usually takes 3-6 seconds and sometimes takes 30.

```
 $sth5 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT activityType, startDate, startTime, duration, quality, type, endTime, activityNum, activityClass FROM ActivityX WHERE user=? AND activityType=? ORDER BY activityNum DESC");
```

In some cases, I tried restricting the rows to be searched in the database and it helped only if I could restrict the rows to be 20,000-40,000 or so.  (I often have to search the full database for the answer.)

```
 $sth5 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT activityType, startDate, startTime, duration, quality, type, endTime, activityNum, activityClass FROM (SELECT * FROM ActivityX ORDER BY activityNum DESC LIMIT $rowBack) s WHERE user=? AND activityType=?");
```

Anything I can do to speed up the query and make it more reliably fast?

I'll be moving to a VPS in the near future which may solve the problem but I don't want to rely on that.

Thanks,

- Jon

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an index on (user, activitytype, activitynum).
I am not sure what you mean by encrypted data being indexable, that is generally not the case with most normal encryption types.

Over and above that, it sounds like you have a huge noisy neighbour problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look in here. [How do you get server CPU usage and RAM usage with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949295/how-do-you-get-server-cpu-usage-and-ram-usage-with-php).

Also should be working on shared. I've seen such indicators in Instant Cms.

Also you can find here some useful tips.
https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-identify-mysql-performance-issues-slow-queries