# How to get current cpu load from a PHP script on Windows?

Tags: php

How can a php script get current cpu load in percentage?
On linux platform we have `sys_loadavg()[0]`, that is not present on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

So far I know there is three methods:

### COM call

```
    $com = new COM('winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}');
    $cpus = $com->execquery('SELECT LoadPercentage FROM Win32_Processor');
    foreach ($cpus as $cpu) { $load = $cpu->LoadPercentage; break; }
```

*com_dotnet* extension required.

### console call to `wmic`

```
    exec('wmic cpu get LoadPercentage', $p);
    return $p[2];
```

### console call to `typeperf`

```
    $_ENV['typeperfCounter'] = '\processor(_total)\% processor time';
    exec('typeperf -sc 1 "'.$_ENV['typeperfCounter'].'"', $p);
    $line = explode(',', $p[2]);
    $load = trim($line[1], '"');
```

1. Note: $_ENV['typeperfCounter'] should be set according system locale. For ru_RU it is

   ```
   $_ENV['typeperfCounter'] = '\Процессор(_total)\% загруженности процессора';
   ```

All they running very slowly (be honestly I think they block execution of current thread for 1 sec to measure load).

Answer (score 0):

Check here my reply.
Function that is compatible with Windows / Linux OS, tested.

In Linux returns an array of 3 values
In Windows return an array of 1 value

[How to get CPU usage and RAM usage without exec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705759/how-to-get-cpu-usage-and-ram-usage-without-exec/29669238#29669238)